# A method that swaps places between two indexes in an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, program-entry-point, swap

I have just created a method that is supposed to swap places between index[0] and index[1] in an array.

However I can't seem to find how i should return this to the main method and then print it out in the swapped order.

What did I do wrong?

```
public class Uppgift4_6a {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] intArray= new int [] {2, 4};
        int l= intArray[0];
        int r= intArray[1];
        System.out.println("right order:" + l + " " + r);
        exchange(intArray, intArray[0], intArray[1]);
        System.out.println("right order:" + l + " " + r);
    }

    public static void exchange (int[] intArray, int l, int r){
        l = intArray[0]; 
        r = intArray[1];
        intArray[1] = l;
        intArray[0] = r;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Passing primitive values (int in this case) to a method **copies** the value.  So changing the value in the method does not change the value in the calling method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to return something ? The array will be updated, as you're passing a reference to an object. **However, `l` and `r` will not be updated**.

Just print out like this

```
System.out.println("right order:" + l + " " + r);
exchange(intArray, intArray[0], intArray[1]);
System.out.println("right order:" + intArray[0] + " " + intArray[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
public static int[] exchange(int[] intArray, int l, int r) {
//             ^^---------------return type
    ....
    return intArray;//<<---------return your result array 
}
```

To print your array you can use `Arrays.toString` :

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(exchange(intArray, intArray[0], intArray[1])));;
```

or you can assign the result to another array for example :

```
int[] result = exchange(intArray, intArray[0], intArray[1]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

---

**Outputs**

```
right order:2 4
[4, 2]
right order:2 4
```

Comment: Ok but is there anyway I can do it with the current method I am using?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful edit!

Comment: @mackanmorre i think all the other answer gives you a good way, so i can't include them information in my answer you can follow any of them :)

Comment: Yes! Very good answers from all of you! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a **misconception**:

```
 exchange(intArray, intArray[0], intArray[1]);
```

does **not at all** affect your variables l and r! It updates `intArray`; but not the primitive values that `intArray[0]` resp. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) evaluate to!

Meaning: the fact that you use the same variable names repeatedly doesn't magically turn those variables into "one" thing. There are **two** variables named l. One exists in `main()`, one exists in `exchange()`. The other core thing to understand: Java does **call by value**; but that means: when passing an **array** to a method, changes to the parameter are **visible** to the caller.

But when passing primitive types such as int, the caller **does not see** updates. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) for all the details.

Answer (score 1):

Your array has been updated. However you are missing a print statement to print out the updated array.

```
System.out.println("right order:" + intArray[0] + " " + intArray[1]);
```

Edit 1: I would suggest that you pencil out the memory model of the array, how it is made available to the exchange method and then this will all be so easy. Remember Java passes by value including references and that array is a reference.